# Grouping item in selectOneMenu Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, selectonemenu

I decide to use group selectItems in selectOneMenu in primefaces and faced with problem
I see decision of my problem [How to group selectItems in selectOneMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626764/how-to-group-selectitems-in-selectonemenu) but it doesn't help me

when I use `<p:selectOneMenu>` it's not OK and generated html like this

```
<div id="manageTournament:gender" class="ui-selectonemenu ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
<div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"><select id="manageTournament:gender_input"
                                                 name="manageTournament:gender_input">
    <option value="">German Cars</option>
    <option value="">American Cars</option>
</select></div>
```

But when I use `<h:selectOneMenu>` it's OK

```
<select id="manageTournament:gender" name="manageTournament:gender" size="1">
<optgroup label="German Cars">
    <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
    <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="Volkswagen">Volkswagen</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="American Cars">
    <option value="Chrysler">Chrysler</option>
    <option value="GM">GM</option>
    <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

My xhtml page

```
<h:form id="manageTournament">
            <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{adminTournamentController.setConditions(false, 1)}"/>
            <p:wizard id="wizard" widgetVar="wiz" style="display: inline-block; width:600px;"
                      flowListener="#{adminTournamentController.onFlowProcess}" nextLabel="#{msg.next_button}" backLabel="#{msg.back_button}">

                <p:tab id="competitionId" title="#{msg.add_tournament}">
                    <p:panel header="#{msg.info_about_tournament}">
                        <h:panelGrid columns="3" olumnClasses="label, value" styleClass="grid">
<p:outputLabel value="#{msg.age_category}" for="gender_edit"/>
                            <p:selectOneMenu  id="gender_edit"
                                             value="#{adminTournamentController.genderAgeId}"
                                             rendered="#{not empty adminTournamentController.tournamentBean.teams}"
                                             disabled="true">
                                <f:selectItems value="#{adminTournamentController.genderAgeList}"/>
                            </p:selectOneMenu>

                            <p:selectOneMenu id="gender"
                                             value="#{adminTournamentController.genderAgeId}"
                                             rendered="#{empty adminTournamentController.tournamentBean.teams}">
                                <f:selectItems value="#{adminTournamentController.genderAgeList}"/>
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                             </p:panel>
                </p:tab>
                <!-- others tabs -->          

            </p:wizard>
</h:form>
```

A need to use selectOneMenu with grouping and I find other article [OptionGroup-support for SelectOneMenu in Primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774348/optiongroup-support-for-selectonemenu-in-primefaces)

But nobody help this guy. Is it possible to resolve my problem?

Comment: Very interesting. Primefaces, in fact, doesn't render `optgroup` tags, just `option` tags. `select` with `options` is hidden, an list which shows options is just 'ul'. Can you post your xhtml and backing bean code for generating items code?

Comment: In future questions, please always mention the versions used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can reproduce it.

[image]

This was apparently a bug in PrimeFaces 3.4.2. It works in [PrimeFaces 3.5](http://primefaces.org/downloads.html) which was released just this week.

[image]

View source code (the bean source code is the same as in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626764/how-to-group-selectitems-in-selectonemenu) which you found):

```html
<o:importConstants type="org.primefaces.util.Constants" var="PrimeFaces" />
<p>PrimeFaces version: #{PrimeFaces.VERSION}</p>
<h:form>
    <p:selectOneMenu>
        <f:selectItems value="#{bean.cars}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

That it worked for me while posting the answer you found is most likely because I was using 3.5 snapshot at that moment.